# How to find out that Facebook App is selected when using Intent to share in Android

Tags: android

How to find out that Facebook App is selected when using Intent to share text message in Android? Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this using the standard chooser dialogs. You are welcome to create your own custom chooser dialog, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.